# Error while calling Cross domain API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a cross domain webservice api from AJAX in my JS, but I am getting an error as:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url2.com/social/polling/get_poll.
>   Origin http://url1.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

I also tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to ***** in header of request, but then to no success, I am getting same error

Below is what I am actually doing:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        data : {
            pollId : pollId
        },
        /* header : {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}, */
        url : "http://url2.com/social/rs/polling/get_poll",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                    '*');
        },

        success : function(response) {
            var html;

            var html = "<div ><h2>" + response.topic + "</h2>";
            for ( var index = 0; index < response.options.length; index++) {
                html = html
                        + "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"option\" value=\""
                        + response.options[index] + "\"  />"
                        + response.options[index] + "<br/>";
            }
            html = html
                    + "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"pollIT("
                    + response.pollId + ", '" + response.topic
                    + "'); \" /></div>";
            $("#question").append("");
            $("#question").append(html);
            html = "";

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I have also tried setting header as

```
header : {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
```

but still no luck. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: do you control url1.com?  You need to have the setting in the web service. not on your request.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain AJAX needs to be allowed on the server you're requesting from, it can't be authorized in the request.

So you'll need access to the server of url1.com If you do, here's a guide on how to enable this access:
http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/cross-domain-browser-json-ajax/

If you don't have access and want a work around for this, you can call a script on your own server with AJAX that will make a CURL request to the foreign server.